# Chrome/Edge/Matlab not response to keyboard after remote desktop reconnect

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard, remote-desktop

I face an issue when using remote desktop(RDP that comes with Windows)

- Some apps will not response keyboard input sometime after reconnect
  RDP(Apps are running on the remote server). Currently I find Chrome,
  Edge, Matlab has this issue.
- When the issue occurs, these apps will simply not response keyboard
  input, just like there is no keyboard input at all. However it
  doesn't mean keyboard is not working for whole RDP session at this
  time, e.g. press win key still will show the windows menu, the
  keyboard works also in some other apps.
- When the issue occurs, mouse clicks are fully functional. e.g.
  broswering with Chrome still work until you need to have a keyboard
  input.
- When the issue occurs, close and relaunch those apps will fix the
  issue. But after another reconnect, it's highly possible the issue
  will come back again.

My build as below.

Server:
Windows 11 Workstation(Host),
Hyper-V Windows 11 Pro(guest),
Remote desktop enabled on guest

Client:
Windows 10 LTSC and use built in Remote Desktop Client to connect.

Previously I suspect that could be a network issue. However, I tried to connect to the guest directly from host via RDP, still there is cerntain possibility for the issue.

Could anyone guide me what could be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems it's not only related to VMs, RDP to the host will be problematic as well sometime.